# Crash on Android using Chrome WebView regarding ChromeColors & resources

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I recently saw a crash while starting a `WebView`:

```
2021-10-08 12:55:56.478 26503-26503/? E/cr_WarmupManager: Inflation exception.
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class <unknown>
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class <unknown>
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ChromeColors requires a value for the com.android.chrome:attr/0_resource_name_obfuscated attribute to be set in your app theme. You can either set the attribute in your theme or update your theme to inherit from Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
        at y12.c(chromium-Monochrome.aab-stable-460606123:5)
        at i00.b(chromium-Monochrome.aab-stable-460606123:4)
        at org.chromium.chrome.browser.compositor.CompositorView.g(chromium-Monochrome.aab-stable-460606123:5)
        at org.chromium.chrome.browser.compositor.CompositorView.<init>(chromium-Monochrome.aab-stable-460606123:5)
        at org.chromium.chrome.browser.compositor.CompositorViewHolder.<init>(chromium-Monochrome.aab-stable-460606123:15)
```

Have you seen anything similar? Could it be due to a [`WebView` update](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview&hl=en&gl=US)?

Comment: Please share your xml code.

Comment: It is using Chrome in the `WebView`, I don't have the xml code. By the way, it ended up being not the root problem.